# One hot encoding when a string is in column of dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, lambda, encoding

I have a column '`amenities`' of my dataframe `df`

[image]

Example:

`amenities
0   {'TV','Wifi','Heater'}
1   {'Heater','Swimming Pool'}
2   {'Pet friendly','Heater'}`

I need to perform one hot encoding sort of operation so that I get a new dataframe like this.

```
amenities   Heater  PF  SP  TV  Wifi
0   {'TV','Wifi','Heater'}  1   0   0   1   1
1   {'Heater','Swimming Pool'}  1   0   1   0   0
2   {'Pet friendly','Heater'}   1   1   0   0   0
```

Preferably with the new column name matches the string. I wrote PF for Pet friendly just for convenience of others.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If columns is filled by strings use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for add original column, also if necessary `strip` `''` from columns names by `rename`:

```
df1 = (df['amenities'].str.strip('{}')
                      .str.get_dummies(',')
                      .rename(columns= lambda x: x.strip("'")))
df2 = df[['amenities']].join(df1)
```

If is filled by sets first convert to strings:

```
df1 = (df['amenities'].astype(str)
                      .str.strip('{}')
                      .str.get_dummies(',')
                      .rename(columns= lambda x: x.strip("'")))
```

Or use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['amenities']),columns=mlb.classes_)
```

---

```
df2 = df[['amenities']].join(df1)

print (df2)
                    amenities  Heater  Pet friendly  Swimming Pool  TV  Wifi
0      {'TV','Wifi','Heater'}       1             0              0   1     1
1  {'Heater','Swimming Pool'}       1             0              1   0     0
2   {'Pet friendly','Heater'}       1             1              0   0     0
```